# Show success message on AJAX success

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have ajax based form submission and on success I want to show a success message. The elements are being generated dynamically by mysql results. Currently the success message for one shows up for all the elements in loop. How can I obtain this for that particular element. Some insight will be very helpful.

```
 <?php if($row['section'] == 1) {?>  
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item active">
            <div class="radio noMargin" id="<?php echo $sectionOne ; ?>info"><?php echo $no ; ?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div><?php echo "<font color='pink'>Ques ID :[".$row['id']."]</font>";?><div class="question"><?php echo $row['question'] ; ?></div>
<div style="float:right; margin-top:-20px;">

Marks:<?php echo $row['marks'] ; ?></div></li>
<?php          
echo '<input type="hidden" name="question[]" id="questionId" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="attempt" value="'.$attemptCount.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="unit_id" value="'.$unit_id.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="chapter_id" value="'.$chapter_id.'">';
$questionId     =   $row['id'] ;  
$sqO =$db->query("SELECT id, options from  tbl_options_mock_question WHERE question_id = ".$questionId."");
while($rowO=mysql_fetch_array($sqO))
{
?>  
    <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
      <div class="radio noMargin">
        <label>
          <input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>"  name="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>"  value="<?php echo $rowO['id'] ; ?>">
          <?php echo $rowO['options'] ; ?></label>
      </div>
    </li> 
<?php } ?>
<div class="successMessage" style="display:none;"><font color="green"><b>Your notes for question is submitted successfully.</b></font></div>
<br>
 <a class="click_notes" data-question-id="<?=$questionId?>"> <font size='2' color='blue'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Notes</font></a> 
<br> 
<div class="demo"></div>

 </ul>

<?php $i++;$no++; ?>
<?php } ?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click_notes').on('click', function() {
    var tid = $(this).data('question-id');
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.demo').html('<div class="comment_form"><span><b>X</b></span><form id="contactForm1" action="submit.php" method="post"><textarea required cols="50" class="span10" name="notes" rows="6"></textarea><br><input class="btn btn-primary" id="submitnotes" name="submit_notes" type="submit" value="Add Notes"><input type="hidden" name="submitValue" value="' + tid + '" /></form><br></div>');
  });

  $(document).on('submit', '#contactForm1', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: this.method,
      url: this.action,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {

        $('.comment_form').hide();
        $(".successMessage").show();
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        console.log('An error occurred.');
        console.log(xhr);
      },
    });
  }).on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide()
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: It seems you have more than one form with the same ID. Use a class and save `$(this)` in the submit, then use relative addressing `$aveForm.closest(somecontainer).find(".successMessage").show()`

Comment: Thanks for this prompt reply. But can you let me know where can I put this. I am not much into jquery so finding it troublesome.

Comment: It is difficult because you posted a lot of PHP. It would be easier to see if you posted an example with 3 items of rendered HTML

Comment: You could also just move the success message outside the loop

Comment: ok . So how  should I proceed?

Comment: @mplungjan Moving of success message out of loop doesnt help

Comment: @Ansh I do not see where `#contactForm1` exists in your example. Your code is all mashed together and does not make a lot of sense. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `#contactForm1` is the form `id` @Twisty

Comment: @Ansh I do not see it in your example. Also what is an example of the data returned by your AJAX call? Any console errors or responses in Network section of your browser?

Comment: `console.log` shows 15 blank rows . I have 7 questions being generated dynamically from mysql under this `<ul>`

Comment: `<form id="contactForm1" action="submit.php" method="post">` in jquery part

Comment: @Ansh right now you have HTML issue, PHP issues, and JavaScript issues. You cannot have `<input>` and `<div>` elements inside the `<ul>` that are outside of `<li>`. Your HTML structure must be correct. If it is not correct, you will have mixed and strange results with jQuery. It's making it very hard to help you and you are not forthcoming with details in your post or in your comments.

Comment: @Ansh the 15 blank rows suggests to me that `error` callback is running maybe? Or that something is calling `console.log` 15 times? To help we really need to see an proper example.

Comment: Thanks @Twisty But let me know how can I open things that you really want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186960/discussion-between-ansh-and-twisty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Fiddle I used for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/gokfth37/41/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item active">
    <div class="radio noMargin" id="section-1-info">
      1
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
    </div>
    <font color='pink'>Ques ID : 1</font>
    <div class="question">
      Question 1
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; margin-top:-20px;">Marks: Marks 1
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" name="question[]" id="questionId" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="attempt" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="unit_id" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="chapter_id" value="1">
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
    <div class="radio noMargin">
      <input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="1" name="optionAns1" value="1">
      <label>Answer 1</label>
      <input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="2" name="optionAns2" value="2">
      <label>Answer 2</label>
      <input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="3" name="optionAns3" value="3">
      <label>Answer 3</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="successMessage" style="display:none;">
      <font color="green">
        <b>Your notes for question is submitted successfully.</b>
      </font>
    </div>
    <br>
    <a class="click_notes" data-question-id="1">
      <font size='2' color='blue'>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Notes
      </font>
    </a>
    <br>
    <div class="demo">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I made some leaps and created HTML based on the PHP code you had. You can see here that I had to correct a lot of HTML Syntax. You should not have `<ul>` that have `<input>` or `<div>` elements as children. It should only be `<li>` elements that can then contain other elements.

So when the "Add Notes" button is clicked, a form is dynamically created that must have a unique ID and all the elements within must have unique IDs. This form will have a Close button, a Text Area, a hidden element and a submit button. When the form is submitted, the data from the form should be submitted via POST to a specific URL and upon successful submission, display the success note.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('.click_notes').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".successMessage").hide();
    $(this).hide();
    var that = $(this);
    var tid = $(this).data('question-id');
    var form = $("<form>", {
      id: "contact-form-" + tid,
      action: "submit.php",
      method: "POST",
      class: "comment-form"
    }).submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr("method"),
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("Success");
          $('.comment-form').hide();
          that.parent().find(".successMessage").show();
          that.show();
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
          console.log('An error occurred.');
          console.log(xhr);
        }
      });
    });
    $("<span>", {
      class: "close btn"
    }).html("X").click(function() {
      that.show();
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }).appendTo(form);
    $("<textarea>", {
      required: true,
      cols: "50",
      class: "span10",
      name: "notes"
    }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "hidden",
      name: "submitValue",
      value: tid
    }).appendTo(form);
    $("<button>", {
      class: "btn btn-primary",
      id: "submit-notes-" + tid,
      type: "submit"
    }).html("Add Notes").appendTo(form);
    $(this).closest('li').find('.demo').html(form);
  });
});
```

One of the benefits of creating content with jQuery is that you can bind callbacks when you create the object. So instead of mucking around with `.on()` you can also just call `.click()` or `.submit()` right when you're creating the objects. Either works, but sometimes one is easier to manage than the other.

In the example above, we create the form, bind a submit callback to it, add other elements, and the replace `#demo` with this newly created content. I also added some extra bits to hide a few things, if they are being shown.

When you see `var that = $(this);` it's sort of a little trick since we do not want to confuse `this` in some of the other callbacks, yet we may need to reference the original `this`, and we can, using `that`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey yes this worked for me. Sorted. But can we do something with the 'X' and the button, they appear not aligned

Comment: @Ansh your post was in regards to the AJAX and the success callback. You can adjust the CSS for the button as you need. As my answer addressed your initial question, I hope you will upvote it and mark it as the answer. If you still need help with the button, you can work on it or post another question if you can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested moving the message outside the loop so you only have ONE message. You could even show it in a dialog

Also you have more than one jQuery loaded. Just load latest or 3.x, not both

1. change id="contactForm" to class="contactForm"
2. The HTML is invalid. Move the `</ul>` to before the demo div
3. It would have been easier if you wrapped each question and demo div in a wrapper, but try this:

---

```
$(document).on('submit', '.contactForm', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $currentForm = $(this);

 ...

  success: function(data) {
    $currentForm.hide();
    $currentForm.prevAll(".successMessage:first").show();
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for this, But no luck. Their is no message displaying . Can something else be done

Comment: You have to do minimum debugging. Since you did not provide useful HTML to play with, I may have a bug in my code. Any console messages? What do you get if you `console.log($currentForm.prevAll(".successMessage:first").text())` for example

Comment: `console.log($currentForm.prevAll(".successMessage:first").text())` is empty.

Comment: moving `</ul>` before `<div demo>` does not shows the text area only.

Comment: Moving it makes the HTML more valid - it does not fix anything

Comment: Ok ok. but doing this complicates the problem more. because the textarea does not appears.